# vertical centering one view inside a LinearLayout with two views

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, footer, centering

i would like to force *gauge* to be centered vertically above *llInner*...
i just don't seem to be able

instead of *llTop* using all the available space it is *llInner* doing it.

thank you

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llTop"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#ff0000">

<eu.sextante.speedlimit.Views.GaugeView
    android:id="@+id/gauge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llInner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:background="#00ff00">

    <eu.sextante.speedlimit.Views.LimitView
        android:id="@+id/limit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:maxHeight="60dip"
        android:maxWidth="60dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `android:gravity="center|right"` instead of `android:gravity="bottom|right"` in your `LinearLayout`

Comment: @R9j, stays the same way... llTop still wraps only around the content leaving the "free" display space to be used by llInner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Relative Layout as main layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llInner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <eu.sextante.speedlimit.Views.LimitView
            android:id="@+id/limit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:maxHeight="60dip"
            android:maxWidth="60dip" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <your.gaugeview
        android:id="@+id/gauge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="dfdg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: it centers on all screen, not on the space above llInner...
but it gave a nice insight.

Comment: the background colors are purely to get a visual on the views distribution (as understandable unless i'm creating an app for 5 year old kids)

Comment: it works with a TableLayout. as i have low reputation i need to wait 8 hours before posting the correct answer, which i'll do by then.